# How to keep track of mobile clients and selectively push data to them?

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I have a Web application and also a corresponding mobile client.

My requirement is to keep track of the devices so that I can selectively push data to them.

I have read about PUBNUB and GCM. Pubnub provides presence service with I think I can achieve the same. But, I cannot afford that cost right now. With GCM I am unable to understand how I can selectively push to a specific handset only. Also, it is Android specific.

How can I achieve the same without spending a lot (some open source variant that I can use) and also support various types of devices (android, ios) with a single service?

Comment: gcm do support ios devices

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi Any leads on how I can selectively push to a device using GCM?

Comment: do you have any criteria for selecting a device ?

Comment: That's something I am still to figure out, but I am thinking it would make sense to identify based on logged in user account.

Comment: then yes you can query that device from your db and send notification to a single device you can follow this tut -> http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I understand that GCM maintains `gcm_regid` with which Google can identify to whom to push data to. Are you aware of any product (open source maybe) that does what GCM does here?

Comment: `parse` offers this service but the free service is for limited usage you can check that on `parse.com`